# Should I delete a question if I figure out the answer shortly after posting it?

Tags: support, deleted-questions

Sometimes I get stuck on something while programming, so I post a question on Stack Overflow to get some help.

I have noticed that when I do this, that suddenly I think differently about the problem I am trying to solve and I end up solving it myself within 5 minutes after being stuck for hours.

After that i feel a bit stupid for posting the question and I answer my own question. Should I delete those questions or just leave them with my own answer?

Comment: I think this is called [Rubber duck debugging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging), where you have to type it out and explain it to someone, thinking about it in a way where you wouldn't have if you were doing it just by yourself.

Comment: @Albzi Which works, I bought rubber ducks for all the devs in my office. Even if it doesn't work, the occasional squeaking is fun

Comment: There is a reason we want a MCVE on debugging questions.  Often times you can find the problem just by making one, or at least know exactly where it is at.

Comment: It's simple, really. Do you think that other people might have the same question, and would find your answer helpful? If so, post it and self-answer. If not, just delete it and move on.

Comment: Since you have to think about how you describe the problem you have to someone who doesn't know anything about your problem you definitely look at your problem differently. This kinda similar to when you learn something and then try to explain it to someone else.

Comment: To add to Cody's point, the other half is whether or not the answer is already readily available.  If you solved the problem by finding an existing answer, then duplicating that solution isn't adding value.

Comment: I usually use my non programmer colleague beside me! Always find the fix to a problem when you have to explain something in non technical terms having to go through the ins and outs in 'laymens' terms! @George. But I'm always happy to invest in an actual duck :P

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No. Post a self-answer so future users (or future you) can find it. Most viewers are from Google.

Obligatory [XKCD](https://xkcd.com/979/):

[image]